# How do I write a dynamically allocated multidimensional struct array to a file?

Tags: c++, fwrite

The struture

```
struct str
{
  int a;
  char b[20];
  int c;
}
```

declaration

```
struct str ** str_array=0;
```

allocation and initialization(use)

```
str_array= new struct str*[100];
for(int i=0;i<100;++i)
   str_array[i]=new struct str[1000];

for(int i=0;i<100;++i)
   for(int j=0;j<1000;++j;
      str_array[i][j].a=j;
       .....
```

now I tried to write content of array like

```
for(int i=0;i<100;++i)
   for(int j=0;j<1000;++j;
     fwrite(str_array[i][j],sizeof(str),1,fname);
```

Problem

> no suitable conversion from **str** to **const void*** exists

I intend to read it with same style.

Comment: Have you considered boost::serialization ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
 fwrite(str_array[i][j],sizeof(str),1,fname);
```

to:

```
 fwrite(&str_array[i][j],sizeof(str),1,fname);
```